# how to fill color in specific area with R

Tags: r

I created a pentagram. The code is

```
p <- cbind(x = c(0, 1, 2,-0.5  , 2.5  ,0), y = c(0, 1, 0,0.6, 0.6,0))
plot(p)
lines(p)
```

[image]

But how can I fill in color like this. I tried to use polygon function but couldn't figure out how to describe the borderline.

[image]

Comment: I think you have to manually calculate coordinates of your polygons by finding intersection points between lines and then use `polygon`. No worries, this is trivial.

Comment: Not quite the complete answer but close: `polygon(p, col="green", angle = 0, density = 100, fillOddEven = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks. But is there any R functions for finding intersection points between lines or I'll just have to calculate them on my own? If I have to calculate the intersections manually, it might appear inaccurate in plot.

Comment: @Gillian I had no idea this can be automated. Upvoting the answer

Comment: @slava-kohut Don't worry I'll start a new question about this. However, it seems that there are better solutions that don't need intersections. Check it below~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`polygon` works with `fillOddEven=TRUE`.

```
plot(p)
lines(p)
polygon(p, col="darkblue", fillOddEven=TRUE)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
p <- structure(c(0, 1, 2, -0.5, 2.5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.6, 0.6, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y")))
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on the `ggplot2` package:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 2,-0.5  , 2.5  ,0), y = c(0, 1, 0,0.6, 0.6,0))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_polygon(fill="blue") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't learnt ggplot but your answer is absolutely helpful for those who want to solve similar problems with ggplot.